# ::deep selector is unknown pseudo selector in blazor application using Rider Jetbrains

Tags: css-selectors, blazor, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to make css isolation for Blazors QuickGrid component. When I use the pseudo selector "::deep" it gives we the warning: " Unknown pseudo selector 'deep'".
How can I fix this and is it possible when using Rider Jetbrains IDE?

````
::deep th.country-name { width: 14rem; }

/* Subtle stripe effect */
 ::deep tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}

/* Don't collapse rows even if they are empty */
::deep tbody tr { height: 1.8rem; }```
````